# Obtain user from Azure Web App using AD authentication

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have an ASP.NET-CORE Azure Web App running using AD authentication (all setup in Azure using the Authentication/Authorization blade). It seems to be functioning as intended as users are requested to login when accessing the site. How can I obtain the current using making the call to the App Service?

I was assuming the current user was obtainable through `User?.Identity.Name` as authentication, but that yields a `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The username can be found in headers under the key `X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-NAME`. To obtain it the following piece of code could be used `Request.Headers["X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-NAME"];`